# WPF TabControl Memory issues

Tags: wpf

If I have the follow TabControl and everything works properly and when I switch to the second tabitem it just shows without no issues.

```
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid </TabItem>
   <TabItem> //datagrid2 </TabItem>
<TabControl>
```

But if i have this xaml, when i click the second tabitem the memory goes out of control

```
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid </TabItem>
<TabControl>
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid2 </TabItem>
<TabControl>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the XAML in your question it seems.. Fixed it for you

Comment: You need to show a bit more of your XAML - we need to see the Panel you use around the TabControls - shooting from the hip, I'd say the DataGrid2's TabControl is placed inside a Grid Row with Height="Auto" or Height="*"

Comment: Yes, you are correct should i make it a definite height?

Comment: thats works post it as an answer so i can mark it correct. thanks man!

Comment: @Goblin, please make your answer as a comment, you'll gain reputation and help users get to the question faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pending more xaml / code in the question (another shoot from the hip answer):

Are you aware that the TabControl in WPF will [dynamically unload the visual tree within TabItems (and their contents) once they are tabbed out of view](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PersistTab.aspx), and the Visual Tree / data therein can be garbage collected? By hosting the two DataGrids in two separate TabControls as per your second code snippet you disable this feature:

```
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid </TabItem>
<TabControl>
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid2 </TabItem>
<TabControl>
```

In the above code you are essentially requiring the .NET framework to load both into memory simultaneously

```
<TabControl>
   <TabItem> //datagrid </TabItem>
   <TabItem> //datagrid2 </TabItem>
<TabControl>
```

The example where both DataGrids are hosted in TabItems on the same TabControl (above) as you switch tabs the memory required for the hidden DataGrid can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer as requested :-).

You need to show a bit more of your XAML - we need to see the `Panel` you use around the `TabControl`s - shooting from the hip, I'd say the `DataGrid2`'s `TabControl` is placed inside a `Grid` `Row` with `Height="Auto"` or `Height="*"`.